# Change aspect ratio of image

Tags: image, artificial-intelligence, aspect-ratio

Is there any way to change the aspect ratio of an image without zooming or removing some parts? I let users upload images but they are of different aspect ratios. I want to convert them to a 1:1 aspect ratio before saving them are there any AI tools or ways to do that?

I tried different AI tools but none of the gave the result I wanted.